# apache doesn't work after upgrade of macOs Sierra

Tags: php, macos, apache, localhost

Hi I'm trying to restart Apache after update of macOs Sierra and I'm getting this error>

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _apr_crypto_block_cleanup   Referenced from:
/usr/local/Cellar/httpd24/2.4.25/bin/httpd   Expected in:
/usr/local/opt/apr-util/libexec/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib  in
/usr/local/Cellar/httpd24/2.4.25/bin/httpd /usr/local/bin/apachectl:
line 79: 94187 Abort trap: 6           $HTTPD -k $ARGV
```

I've tried to reinstall apache and reinstall php56 and php70 but without any progress on this. Please does anybody know what to do?

Answer (score 54):

Just had the same issue myself and looks like and issue with the apr-util package.

To solve this as I use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) I simply did `brew reinstall apr-util` and this fixed my issue.

If you're using another package manager try to reinstall apr-util with their correct syntax.

Comment: I found that the issue can also happen at random after a reboot, and this command still fixes it.

Comment: Error happens and this command fixes it on El Capitan as well.

Comment: this fixes on sierra too, (After a brew php upgrade)

Comment: Still have the same issue on macOS 10.12

Comment: Note if you're coming from Google: Be sure to read exactly which library is broken, and reinstall _that_ one. I had to reinstall `apr` itself to fix a similar error

Comment: It still works in macOS Monterey. When I run `brew services`, `httpd` status was error and file path was blank. You saved me.

Comment: I had the same issue with apache installed via Homebrew. The message was Symbol not found: _apr_bucket_alloc_aligned_floor
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/httpd/2.4.52/bin/httpd