# Installing httpd and php in Mac OS 12

Tags: php, macos, apache, homebrew

I updated my MacOS to Monterey (12.0.1) and my PHP stopped working.
MacOS 12 seem to have removed PHP support.

I'm currently trying to configure everything using homebrew.

After installation, when I try to start the httpd, I'm getting the following errors-

```
user@Laptop folder % /opt/homebrew/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND                  
dyld[15738]: Symbol not found: _apr_bucket_file_set_buf_size
  Referenced from: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/httpd/2.4.51/bin/httpd
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libaprutil-1.0.dylib
zsh: abort      /opt/homebrew/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

Am I missing any package for _apr_bucket_file_set_buf_size?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yeah, what a nightmare! PHP is no longer supported natively in MacOS 12. I switched to Homebrew's Apache (httpd) package.

But switching from native Apache to Homebrew's Apache wasn't easy.

There are lots of guides out there on how to install Homebrew's Apache. I won't go into them here.

But after installing, configuring, and starting, I was receiving a similar error to your "*apr_bucket*" error. I ran `brew reinstall apr-util` and that did the trick.
Found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41871228/1623341

After that, I removed Homebrew's Apache `brew remove httpd`, then reinstalled `brew install httpd`, then updated the httpd.conf file, then started `brew services start httpd`. That seemed to do the trick for me.

Comment: There are lots of guides out there on how to install Homebrew's Apache. I won't go into them here.

Could you give a link to one?  It appears that my 12.0.1 installation has the following for location of php_module: /etc/apache2/httpd.conf:177:LoadModule php_module /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so.  That doesn't look like a homebrew locaton.  How to remove current apache and install using homebrew?

Answer (score 1):

I had to sign the homebrew PHP module using MacOS codesign.
Finally, Apache and PHP are working in my MacOS Monterey.

Kudos to the original author for the detailed solution
https://www.simplified.guide/macos/apache-php-homebrew-codesign