# Can't start httpd - Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/*/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist` exited with 5

Tags: apache

Just tried accessing my localhost today, but it doesn't work. I worked yesterday, but I believe it's because my Mac crashed. I've tried started httpd again with brew services start httpd. This results in:

Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/UserName/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist` exited with 5.

Have tried reinstalling httpd, but it still gives the same error.
Any ideas what the cause can be?

Comment: Following the "Apache Installation" guide on https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-ventura-apache-multiple-php-versions helped me fixing this.

Answer (score 58):

I had the same problem after I upgraded to macOS Monterey. But I solved my issue via these commands.

**Unload homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist**

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist
```

**And then load it again:**

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist
```

After that I used this command to start httpd again.

```
brew services start httpd
```

Comment: I was having the same issues with Nginx. I had to do @Dave Myburgh's solution followed by this to get it working (replacing httpd for nginx in file paths, etc).

Comment: This weird! it also fixed "httpd error  256 root" error! thanks.

Answer (score 52):

Just thought I'd share what worked for me for anyone else still stuck...

It seemed I had a version of apache running which was stopping the brew version. (thought I'd removed the built in apache already!).

This also happened after my Mac crashed and got the exact same error message but I did:

**Stop brew httpd service completely**

```
brew services stop httpd
```

**Stop Mac Apache leftovers**

```
sudo apachectl -k stop
```

**Start brew httpd again**

```
brew services start httpd
```

Started like a charm and solved my issue.

Comment: Thank you, 
Wasted an hour trying to work out why my local server just stopped working, running sudo apachectl -k stop showed that I had a site configured in my httpd-vhost.conf that I had deleted in my sites folder in my last dev session.

Warning: DocumentRoot [/Users/xxxxxx/Sites/xxxxxxxx/public_html] does not exist

Deleting that entry, restarting the server and I'm back in business :)

Comment: @DerekOBrien
Great to hear! Quick tip - you can also use command `sudo apachectl configtest`
This will tell you if there's any issues with your current apache config without having to stop apache. Usually good to run this after any config changes or big changes to Sites directory.

Comment: @Fez thanks for this.  httpd successfully starts but is stopped right away on its own.  Anyone happens to know why?  I got the same issue after a computer crash.

Comment: The solution works but the problem persists after every reboot.

Comment: @user3072843 - Likely due to your config having it auto load on startup. A possible solution would be to unload the default mac apache so that it does not auto load. That way you're left with only Brew httpd running. Of course I don't know what version of anything you're running but see this example of unload: https://superuser.com/a/986792

Comment: @biko - Could be a number of reasons. Config, bad install etc. Can't really recommend much without looking at some logs or error codes/messages.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem after any Restart my Macbook.
I'm using Macbook Air m1 and Monterey OS version.

I have solved my problem with these 4 command

At first run:

```
sudo apachectl -k stop
```

After that run these three command:
(note: do not run as sudo)

```
launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist

launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist

brew services start httpd
```

Then you can see run services with command below:

```
brew services list
```

Answer (score 8):

After trying ALL the solutions proposed all over the place, what finally did it for me was changing the owner of the log files in /usr/local/var/log/httpd to my user, instead of root.

`sudo chown [username] *`

This took me hours to figure out, sadly - I even removed and reinstalled httpd (which was actually a good thing, because there was a n older version's keg knocking around back there).

Comment: Saved my day too, many thanks! My logs are in `/opt/homebrew/var/log/httpd/` though.

Answer (score 3):

So after trying a lot of things, this seemed to work:

Trying what Volex suggests here ([brew services. Cant start service. get "Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68975769/brew-services-cant-start-service-get-bootstrap-failed-5-input-output-error)) gave me a more precise error message.

The new error message led me to this:
[apache doesn't work after upgrade of macOs Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41856344/apache-doesnt-work-after-upgrade-of-macos-sierra)
brew reinstall apr-util fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

for me I got quite same problem once I have tried to start `postgresql` forgetting that I have already started it, after stopping it and started it again it worked

```
user@users-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew services start postgresql
Warning: Use postgresql@14 instead of deprecated postgresql
Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/user/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14.plist` exited with 5.
user@users-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew services stop postgresql 
Warning: Use postgresql@14 instead of deprecated postgresql
Stopping `postgresql@14`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `postgresql@14` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14)
user@users-MacBook-Pro ~ % 
user@users-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew services start postgresql
Warning: Use postgresql@14 instead of deprecated postgresql
==> Successfully started `postgresql@14` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@14)
user@users-MacBook-Pro ~ %
```

Answer (score 1):

After having tried all the solutions in this post without success, I finally found the solution that worked for me.

I don't know how, I don't why but the owner of the log files was `root`. The fact is the `httpd` service does NOT start in `sudo`... #deadlock.

I just changed the owner of the `access_log` and `error_log` files from `/usr/local/var/log/httpd` :

```
sudo chown <my_regular_user> access_log
sudo chown <my_regular_user> error_log
```

re-install httpd with brew :

```
brew reinstall httpd
```

execute a automatic-suggested command :

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/httpd/2.4.57.reinstall
```

and finaly restart my `httpd` service

```
brew services restart httpd
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases will help restart HTTPD.

```
brew services restart httpd
```

It happens to me when the PC crashes for some reason and httpd is running, but localhost is "down".
Or you can stop httpd and restart PC. Then start httpd and it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting `access_log` and `error_log` in the `log` directory may help you reproduce the problem as sometimes those files are not writable.

After deleting them, those files will be created by the user and the error will be logged there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, because I'm in an Apple Silicon Mac, I had to reinstall Apache:

```
brew uninstall httpd
brew install httpd
```

And check the paths of the *php_module* in *httpd.conf* file:

The path I was using was for the previous Intel based Macs:

```
LoadModule php_module /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so
```

I've changed this part of the path from `/usr/local/` to `/opt/homebrew/`:

```
LoadModule php_module /opt/homebrew/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so
```